# XPath - Select all <p> elements does not work

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I have some basic selenium code and an xpath expression that performs well.

The xpath:

```
/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr//td/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]
```

selects the section I'm interested in, containing many

elements.

however, append '//p' like so:

```
/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr//td/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]//p
```

does NOT select only those

elements. Instead, what I ended up with is a single  element.

I'm obviously missing something basic. This is an example of what my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

wd = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

wd.get("http://someurl.html")


# appending //p here is the problem that finds only a single <a> element
elems = wd.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]//p")

print elems.get_attribute("innerHTML").encode("utf-8", 'ignore')

wd.close()
```

EDIT: solved by using find_element**s**_by_xpath instead of find_element as suggested (thanks, Alexander Petrovich, for spotting this).

Comment: What url are you working with?

Comment: I don't want to disclose the url if it's irrelevant.

I may be wrong, but if I'm wrong I'd like to know why.

Sorry if it sounds rude :)

Is my code OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use such locators. Shorten them a bit. Something like `//table[@attr='value']/tbody/tr[2]//p`
2. To select multiple elements, use `find_elements_by_xpath()` method (it returns a list of WebElement objects)
3. You will not be able to use `elems.get_attribute()`. Instead, you'll have to iterate through the list

   ```
   elems = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("/your/xpath")
   for el in elems:
       print '\n' + el.get_attribute('innerHTML').encode("utf-8", 'ignore')
   ```

Comment: Thanks!

These locators are automatically generated via firefox :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani I've added a tip how to shorten your xpath. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). w3schools is not the best tutorial, but you can get some useful info there

Comment: MSDN has a nice xpath example section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx